# Linq и пошаговая отладка

Tags: c#, linq

Господа, подскажите, пожалуйста, как понимать. Есть массив строк. К данному массиву я обращаюсь через LINQ запрос. Ранее я предполагал, что когда выполняется запрос, то формируется определенный результат, который сохраняется в определенном объекте (своего внутреннего типа), и этот объект реализует IEnumerable. Ну дальше foreach уже работает с этим объектом.

Однако я выполнил программу в пошаговом режиме и потерялся ))).
В информации об отладке при первом же обращении к переменной запроса v в разделе "Представление результатов" сразу же появляется готовый ответ (см. рисунок), как я и ожидал. НО я предполагал, что на этом и конец. Однако при дальнейшей пошаговой отладке компилятор почему-то лезет в код запроса и как бы пошагово получает тот результат, который уже мне был показан в разделе "Представление результатов".

Зачем он это делает, если результат уже известен?

Сам код. Понимаю, что запрос корявый, но это в учебных целях.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] s = { "Gleb", "Pavel", "Guzel", "Sergey", "Mainsis", "Berkak" };
            var v = from str in s
                    where str.Length > 4
                    select str
                        into Temp
                        let x = Temp.LastIndexOf('l')
                        where x != -1 && Temp.Substring(x) == "l"
                        select Temp;
            foreach (var Result in v)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Result);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы выполняете этот код под дебагом. Соответственно, Было бы странно, если бы при отладке вы не могли видеть состояние локальных переменных и/или не могли пошагово выполнить код и отследить это выполнение. Поэтому для таких целей необходимо чтобы данные могли быть заранее просчитаны. Вероятно (разумеется, я могу лишь предполагать, поскольку не знаю устройства отладчика VS) под эти богоугодные делишки выделяется отдельный поток, который по мере необходимости просчитывает то, что необходимо для просмотра отладочной информации. Разумеется, этот гипотетический фоновый поток - особенность режима отладки, и код вашей программы знать о нем не знает и не может использовать его результаты. Точнее даже, сделать так, чтобы собственно программа могла использовать эти предварительно вычисляемые отоладчиком результаты разумеется было бы можно, но вот зачем? Слишком уж странная необходимость

З.Ы. совершенно не в тему, однако, [[@polyakov_s](/users/19379/polyakov_s)](/users/19379/polyakov_s) позвольте полюбопытствовать, почему вы всех господами называете? Вы сами, извините, конечно, из холопов?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Не, ну господами называют не только же холопы своих господ. Так еще обращаются к групповому скоплению интеллигенции другой интеллигент. )))

Comment: @polyakov_s про холопов я сказал исключительно не всерьез. Я имею в виду, что выглядит это довольно неуклюже если честно

Comment: ))) Привычка. Но спасибо за замечание, буду следить за собой

Comment: Я думал, что при первом обращении к переменной запроса, компилятор создает объект, который содержит ВСЕ результаты этого запроса (например, если запрос к массиву строк, то при первом обращении к переменной запроса, компилятор перебирает все что можно, что нельзя фильтрует и создает объект со всеми результатами). И с этим объектом содержащим результаты работает цикл foreach.
Но при пошаговой отладке я наблюдаю в цикле foreach идет обращение к коду запроса каждый раз когда, наступает новый шаг цикла. 
То есть получается, что не создается этот объект содержащий другие объекты с результатами ??

Comment: Почитайте Джона Скита C# in Depth. Там хорошо описано, как работает LINQ. В нем есть такое понятие, как нематериализованное представление запроса. В вашем случае в переменной v как раз содержатся не результаты запроса, а только информация о том, как их получить. А вот материализация происходит тогда, когда вы начинаете итерировать переменную v в цикле foreach. А отладочный режим на то и отладочный, чтобы показывать вам значения. Поэтому вы видите уже материализованные результаты запроса, а когда начинаете выполнять программу пошагово, еще раз видите, как эти результаты материализуются.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ.

Comment: Для просмотра значений во время отладки можно создавать визуализаторы.... Собственно можно реализовать и такой, что не будет извлекать все данные сразу. А так, я недавно наткнулся на один проект (не сочтите за рекламу- не имею никакого к нему отношения) oz-code, в презентации которого https://vimeo.com/98856183 показаны возможности по визуализации в том числе и LINQ запросов.